# Using the Karmarkar method in Scilab

Tags: linear-programming, scilab

I am new in Scilab, I am planning to use it to do the linear programming. I googled and found this code:

```
Aeq = [
2 0 6
0 3 5
];
beq = [8;15;30];
c = [30;50];
[xopt]=karmarkar(Aeq,beq,c);
```

But it seems there is a problem with the karmarkar. Can anyone tell me how to fix my problem? I tried to use `help karmarkar` because I think it might be the same with Matlab but it didn't work.

Comment: What is this "problem"?

Comment: you should change the arguments: [xopt]=karmarkar(Aeq,c,beq);

Comment: The person's name is [Karmarkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narendra_Karmarkar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters `Aeq` and `beq` represent linear equality constraints. Each row of `Aeq` has the coefficients of an equation, and the corresponding row of `beq` is the right hand side. Therefore, the number of rows in `Aeq` and `beq` must be the same.

Also, the number of rows of `c` must be equal to the number of variables you have, in this case three.

To summarize: when you have m constraints and n variables, the matrices have the following sizes:

- `Aeq` is m by n
- `beq` is m by 1
- `c` is n by 1

Working example:

```
Aeq = [
2 0 6
0 3 5
]
beq = [8;15]
c = [30;50;70]
[xopt]=karmarkar(Aeq,beq,c)
```